# OWA Message compose origin detection from add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have been wondering, is there a way to detect whether the addin is running in the deeplink version of the message compose  or in the normal owa message compose via the "usual route" ?

Deeplink(https://outlook.office365.com/mail/deeplink/compose)

Usual route (https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox ---> New Message)

**What I tried:**

**1)** `window.location.href` gives me the location of the js page in my webserver.

**2)** `parent.document.location` gives me *"Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame."*.

I read that (for security reasons) an IFRAME can only read the origin of the pages in the IFRAME itself.

Can the office-js library natively detect which message compose link is being used?

Comment: There is no way / api to detect this currently. Can you please tell us what is your use-case? By detecting this, what exactly you are trying to achieve in your add-in?

Comment: Thanks @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, in the end I managed to complete my task using API Calls. Originally I wanted to trigger an event (interacting with the email compose form) only from the https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose scenario (while doing nothing from the normal way to access the mail compose).

Comment: the deeplink link changed from https://outlook.office365.com/mail/deeplink/compose to https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose as of now (in my case).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way / api to detect this currently.

Thanks to @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT